# react-big-calendar show tasks instead of just title and description

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I'm using `react-big-calendar` component to schedule tasks, but it has just `title` and `description`, how can i create a box has `<a>` tag and customize it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There ain't any option in the [APIs](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#api) to do exactly what you are looking for.
I assume you want to make the schedules hyper-links, so that it could be opened in a different view.

Why not make use of `onDoubleClickEvent` or `onSelectEvent`, once you are in the event handler, you could show a modal, redirect to another page, or what ever you wanted to do.